# Here Maps how to create address suggestions iOS SDK Premium?

Tags: ios, here-api

I'm developing an iOS app using Here Maps. Current SDK version is 3.1, but I also checked with 3.3.

The app has a text field for searching the address. It is essential to suggest the address for the user of the closest partial search string, like autosuggestion.

Currently, I'm using geocoder request:

```
NMAGeocodeRequest *request = [[NMAGeocoder sharedGeocoder]
createGeocodeRequestWithQuery:searchText searchRadius:10000
searchCenter:[currentPosition coordinates]];
```

with current position of the iPhone (checked) and radius 10km.

But in result I'm receiving results from all over the world.

Is there a better way to do it with Here Maps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NMAAutoSuggestionRequest`, it handles this use case.

[1] [Text AutoSuggestion Requests User Guide](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/places.html#places__autosuggestion-search-requests)

Comment: Doc provided says it is a beta feature. Is it a part of standard iOS Framework? Can I find somewhere SDK version which includes this features?

Comment: @Mackode Yes technically this is a beta feature, so the details of the API could change in future SDK versions, in which case you would need to update your app code to adapt to the changes while integrating the new SDK version. This API has been present since SDK version 3.2

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually, I think it is not a proper solution. I've tested AutoSuggestionRequest and the results are all around the places, not the addresses. E.g. I search for 'Pio' and as result I receive city, main street, etc. and not address propositions (suggestions) as I expect. Is there a way to tell AutoSuggestionRequest to find me only addresses, like in competitor's maps, like here:

(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

where I choose surrounding (boundingbox) and searched phrase?